# How to detect the page width and height in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want some help with a little thing in html/javascript, how i can make a javascript code for detect the page width and height and when it is smaller than I want just pops a alert telling "press Ctrl -" to adjust. (I know how to do the message, only need help with the detection of page size)

Thanks!

Comment: Not, i just need help.

Comment: Use CSS media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Fast code snippet for JQuery:

```
if ($(document).height() < minHeight || $(document).width() < minWidth) {
    // call popup
}
```

`minHeight` and `minWidth` are variables you should define.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Ctrl - means you want browser height and width for large screen purpose
when you press Ctrl - after that follow this step (easy way for get width,height)

```
Press F12 - > Click on Console -> now right side under search option [in fire bug window] type window.innerWidth then select window.innerWidth and press run button which is exact under this window (bottom) and  check in console [bottom] browser print window.innerWidth. Do same for get window.innerHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution to detect the page width and height

```
var pageWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    pageHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
alert('Page Width '+pageWidth);
alert('Page Height '+pageHeight);
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ENPb7/1/)